# what is the meaning of UL & LL in elevator button

Tags: vocabulary

I knew that "G"means ground, but I don't know UL and LL means what, thanks.

Comment: Upper Lever (or Lobby), Lower Level (or Lobby), [according to Google](http://elevation.wikia.com/wiki/Floor_numbering)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because context-specific abbreviations like this aren't really about learning English

Answer (score 2):

Elevator button labels like this can be very context-specific. Some buildings have special names for certain floors, and abbreviations on the elevator labels will refer to those.

Without any special knowledge, I'd guess that UL and LL are Upper Level and Lower Level.